# Работа со словарями python2.7

Tags: словари, python-2.7

У меня есть массив чисел:

```
0x0000:  023d 0017 068e 98a7 b047 6520 8100 a100
0x0010:  425c 564c 414e 3040 b1d2 b1d2 0138 0000
0x0020:  004a 0000 0000 0132 0001 fd84 8fa6 012b
0x0030:  012b 0000 0000 0000 ffff 0000 0000 0118
0x0040:  0049 0104 0000 0000 0001 e3d5 ba3f 0000
0x0050:  0001 0000 0000 be9a 9fbe 0000 0000 0000
0x0060:  0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000
0x0070:  0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000
0x0080:  0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000
0x0090:  0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000
0x00a0:  0000 0000 0000 0000 0098 0000 0100 0000
0x00b0:  0100 0000 0001 0000 0001 4523 d70a 3e80
0x00c0:  0000 0000 0000 3e4c cccd 0000 0000 0000
0x00d0:  412f 0000 1800 0002 0000 0000 7ef4 000f
0x00e0:  4240 0400 0000 0000 0000 0000 0001 010c
0x00f0:  0602 0001 ffff 0000 0000 7001 0000 0000
0x0100:  0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000
0x0110:  0001 0000 7fff 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000
0x0120:  0000 0000 0001 00be 0000 0000 0000 0100
0x0130:  0300 0100 0c00 0100 0000 0000 0000 0000
0x0140:  0000 0392 0002 0100 0000 0000 0000
```

Я считываю его с помощью subline.strip() и формирую словарь, однако когда я пытаюсь получить ключи словаря методом .keys() выходит это:

['0x00e0', '0x00d0', '0x0130', '0x0140', '0x00c0', '0x0020', '0x0100', '0x00f0', '0x0010', '0x0000', '0x0120', '0x0050', '0x0040', '0x0110', '0x0090', '0x0080', '0x0030', '0x00b0', '0x0070', '0x0060', '0x00a0'].

Почему ключи выводятся не по порядку, причем при каждом перезапуске кода этот неправильный порядок сохраняется?

Answer (score 0):

А кто обещал, что в словаре будет соблюдён порядок ключей? Это в Python 3.6+ есть.
[Цитата](https://pythonz.net/references/named/dict/)

> Порядок ключей Данные в обычном словаре упорядочены по очередности
> добавления ключей, начиная с 3.6 (в 2.7 — не упорядочены, но
> последовательность детерминирована, воспроизводима; в 3.5 — не
> упорядочены, последовательность не детерминирована, не воспроизводима
> между запусками).
>
> Если требуется хранить порядок, в котором в словарь были добавлены
> элементы (например для обхода этих элементов), следует использовать
> collections.OrderedDict().